# как вытащить данные из бд django

Tags: python, django

не бейте сильно это мой первый раз когда я вообще работаю с питоном так тут сразу фреимворк(～￣▽￣)～

```
#profile.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block title %} Профиль {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   <h2>Профиль {{ user.username }}</h2>
   {% if user.first_name and user.last_name %}
       <p>Здравствуйте, {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}   {{ user.image }}</p>

   {% else %}
   {% endif %}
   <h3>ваши записи  </h3>
<p>{{record.title}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

```
#views.py
class RecordingView(CreateView):
    form_class = RecordingForm
    template_name = "account/Recording.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main:register_done')
```

```
#models.py
class RecordingBase(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        pass
```

```
#forms.py
class RecordingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def save(self, commit=True):
        record = super().save(commit=False)
        record.save()
        return record

    class Meta:
        model = RecordingBase
        fields = ('title', 'date')
```

пока это все что у меня есть

Закинул в бд,
а вытащить не могу(

Comment: Посмотрите вот тут (немного устарело, но вполне доходчиво объясняется) - [создание моделей в django](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/django_models/)

Comment: более того, если Вы начнете именно с модели, то потом будет проще создавать формы и ввод данных в базу перестанет быть проблемой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block title %} Профиль {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   <h2>Профиль {{ user.username }}</h2>
   {% if user.first_name and user.last_name %}
       <p>Здравствуйте, {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.surname }}  {{ user.image }} </p>

   {% else %}
   {% endif %}
   <h3>ваши записи  </h3>
   {% for item in record_data %}
      {% if user.id == item.name_id %}
         <p>{{ item.title }} {{ item.date }}</p>
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

```
class RecordingView(CreateView, ListView):
    model = RecordingBase
    form_class = RecordingForm
    template_name = "account/Recording.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main:register_done')
```

```
class RecordingBase(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(AdvUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        pass
```

```
class RecordingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def save(self, commit=True):
        record = super().save(commit=False)
        record.save()
        return record

    class Meta:

        model = RecordingBase
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'date')
```